# Different or no results in with mysql select in php

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a database table with a `SMALLINT` field `parent_id`.

My test select looks like:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT id, title FROM categories WHERE parent_id = 1 ");
$query->execute();             

$results = $query->fetchAll();

echo json_encode($results);
```

Everything works fine, as long as the number in the where clause is less then `10`. Starting with `10`, the result is still correct if there is only one matching record. If there are more records with `parent_id = 10`, I get an error message back from my ajax call that says:

```
Unexpected end of input
```

If I start the select in `PhpMyAdmin`, it returns all the matching rows.

Comment: Have you try to use another way instead of prepare method ? Your ajax open connexion each time ?

Comment: Do `var_dump($results);` and post the output.

Comment: Show us the result json and client-side JS.  The code you posted is fine.

Comment: I suspect you're getting an error, so the response isn't valid JSON. Take a look at the response in the Network tab of the browser console.

Comment: No idea, what's happening here. As soon as I add the proposed var_dump($results); statement, the ajax call returns with error message "Unexpected token a".

Comment: Finally, I found out that it is an encoding problem. There was a value with a french acent in the result set that caused the problem. When I removed the acent, everything works fine. There is another thing that I do not understand... The response of the ajax call seems to contain the information twice, one time as associative array and also as indexed array:
[{"id":"18","0":"18","title":"Cafe","1":"Cafe"},{"id":"19","0":"19","title":"Canteen","1":"Canteen"}, ....

For me its ok but there it means double data traffic ...